# How to make connectors (USB, VGA,...) external in Zybo Zynq 7000

Tags: vhdl, zynq

I have recently enrolled in a course of microelectronics in my university, and I have bought a Zybo Zynq -7000 development board. I have already developed different applications in VHDL language. Now I want to use the USB and VGA connectors, so I would need to make them available from the hardware design point of view. I have been reading through a lot of tutorials about how to make these connectors external, but I have had any success so far. I know that these connectors are already connected to the internal ARM, but as I said, I am not able to make them external and use them with VHDL code.

If I cannot do it by myself, I will have to manually connect an additional USB port to the digital PMOD connectors, but it would be very frustrating, since I want to learn to use the board's own connectors.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The USB connector is connected to a USB PHY (Microchip USB3320
USB 2.0 Transceiver Chip). The PHY is connected directly to the processing system using MIO Bank 1/501 [1, pg14].

The VGA connector is connected to programmable logic [1, pg17]. You can use it to build your own VHDL VGA controller and watch the output on a screen.

[1] http://www.digilentinc.com/data/products/zybo/zybo_rm_b_v6.pdf